Troubleshooting white VGA LED on ASUS B550M motherboard
I'd like to ask. What can I do to fix my pc? Yesterday I turned it off as usual, but today the PC won't boot and the VGA led is constantly white.
Pc specs:

Ryzen 5 1600, stock cooler
Gtx 1050ti, powered through PCIe slot
ASUS B550M WiFi
2x Kingston FURY 8 GB 2400MHz
2x Kingston FURY 16 GB 2666MHz

When booting following happens:

DRAM led blinks up yellow
Cpu led blinks up red
Disks spin up
VGA led lights up white and it stays that way

I tried draining cmos and even changed the battery, this allowed me to get to:

Press f1 to recover bios settings

After which the screen turned on and I got to the bios.
Bios was not updated so I did that and it did not help.
I don't think my GPU is dead, because the I shouldn't see the bios.
I tried reseating my GPU and RAM, which did nothing.
I tried seating gpu into a different slot, which did nothing.
What do you guys think, is this a hardware issue(my best guess is that motherboard is done) or is it something that can be fixed without replacing parts?
EDIT:
So I tested the system with a known-to-be-working GPU, and almost nothing changed. I got to the beeps. First time the beep code was 1 long 3 short - a GPU issue (big news). Second time pc beeped as normal but no video was outputted. I also tried both cards in both PCIe 16 slots on my motherboard, but nothing changed. With working one, I got to the beeps at least, but it tells me nothing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

So the VGA led is turned on but you don’t believe it’s the GPU despite, it definitely could be the motherboard, but it’s odd for a motherboard to just fail and definitely more common for a GPU to fail. Is Ryzen 5 1600 the exact CPU you have?

@Ramhound yes R5 1600 is my CPU, it has no integrated graphics, that's why I'm not convinced it's a GPU problem. I'm trying to get some parts to try exchanging them.

I don't think my GPU is dead, because the I shouldn't see the bios While this makes sense at first glance, things are way more complicated than this. A GPU can fail and still output the VESA mode required for the firmware, i.e, a partial failure, good enough for the most basic of the modes but nothing else.

@ChanganAuto, I see, I should have a spare GPU by tomorrow so I will test this.

@ChanganAuto I tested with another GPU and still nothing changes

Ok, so after testing it seems that the processor died, GPU works fine in a new computer. CPU was switched out and pc came to life. thank you for pointers.
